# MySQL concat UNION GROUP BY row results

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query to return me the total of cities i have on my DB.

Ok lets me introduce: one person can have his address, but he can also have the address associated to his work address. And i want to return te total of cities where the person are.

Supposing i have

```
Pablo living in Lisbon but working in Porto
Jim   living in Paris  and working in Paris
May   living in Lisbon and working in Paris

I have i should have a result like:  
Paris  - 3  
Lisbon - 2  
Porto  - 1
```

After all, my query is:

```
SELECT  
  entity_address.city  as name, 
  entity_address.city as id, 
  COUNT(entity_address.city) as count_all
FROM `entities` LEFT JOIN enterprises_entities ON entities.id = enterprises_entities.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN entities AS `enterprises` ON enterprises.id = enterprises_entities.enterprise_id
 LEFT JOIN addresses as enterprise_address ON enterprise_address.id = enterprises_entities.address_id
 LEFT JOIN addresses as entity_address ON entity_address.entity_id = entities.id
 LEFT JOIN person_titles ON person_titles.id = entities.title_id AND entities.title_type = 'PersonTitle'
 LEFT JOIN enterprise_activities ON enterprise_activities.id = enterprises.title_id AND enterprises.title_type = 'EnterpriseActivity'
 LEFT JOIN positions ON entities.position_id = positions.id 

WHERE enterprise_address.city != '' OR entity_address.city != ''
GROUP BY name

UNION

SELECT 
  enterprise_address.city as name,
  enterprise_address.city as id, 
  COUNT(enterprise_address.city) as count_all
FROM `entities` LEFT JOIN enterprises_entities ON entities.id = enterprises_entities.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN entities AS `enterprises` ON enterprises.id = enterprises_entities.enterprise_id
 LEFT JOIN addresses as enterprise_address ON enterprise_address.id = enterprises_entities.address_id
 LEFT JOIN addresses as entity_address ON entity_address.entity_id = entities.id
 LEFT JOIN person_titles ON person_titles.id = entities.title_id AND entities.title_type = 'PersonTitle'
 LEFT JOIN enterprise_activities ON enterprise_activities.id = enterprises.title_id AND enterprises.title_type = 'EnterpriseActivity'
 LEFT JOIN positions ON entities.position_id = positions.id 

WHERE enterprise_address.city != '' OR entity_address.city != ''
GROUP BY name 

order by count_all DESC 

LIMIT 5
```

Ok the query is a little bit complex i understand. But my problem is the result it's not agrouped like i would:

```
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | name    | id      | count_all |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Lisbon  | Lisbon  |      5100 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Lisbon  | Lisbon  |       932 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Paris   | Paris   |       430 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Porto   | Porto   |       270 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Paris   | Paris   |        92 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
```

I would like to receive like:

```
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | name    | id      | count_all |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Lisbon  | Lisbon  |      6032 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Paris   | Paris   |       512 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Porto   | Porto   |       270 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | London  | London  |        80 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Berlin  | Berlin  |        10 |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
```

How can i write my query to perform me the desired values.
Thank you!

Comment: To downvote please explain me the reason.

Comment: why don't you just count the cities in the addresses table? // i didn't downvote

Comment: @i-joey Because i'm filtering the entities. and i need the result on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to `SUM` the aggregated values from those two queries, that is:

```
SELECT t.id, SUM(t.count_all)
FROM (
  SELECT entity_address.city as id, COUNT(entity_address.city) as count_all
  FROM /* rest of your first query */
  UNION
  SELECT enterprise_address.city as id, COUNT(enterprise_address.city) as count_all
  FROM /* rest of your second query */
) t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: @workdreamer: Also move any `LIMIT` out of the `UNION` subquery, into the exterior query.

Comment: Result: I had to preserve the group by on the first and second query.

This is a very clever solution. Thank you.